# Хэш функция на битовых операциях

Tags: хеширование

Посоветуйте пожалуйста быструю хэш функцию на битовых операциях.
Хэш функция нужна для хэширования чисел.
Сам использовал такую хэш функцию "(( a * x ) % c + b) % c" но она очень медленная.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А вам зачем? Самый простой вариант брать младшие n бит числа. x & 0xFFFF, например

Comment: Мне нужна построить хэш таблицу поэтому такой вариант x & 0xFFFF не подойдет. Слишком много коллизий. Хотелось бы что-то с AND, OR, XOR, <<, >>.

Comment: Если у вас [умножение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996028/7286264) в самом деле медленное, то попробуйте с вашими данными что-нибудь [отсюда](https://gist.github.com/badboy/6267743)